# How to add second bottom header to Tabulator.js?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

Is there any way to add second bottom header in Tabulator.js?

I could not provide any code because I have no idea how to do so. I checked documentation and Google and I am not able to find anything.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I think you can find tour answer on these thread: https://github.com/olifolkerd/tabulator/issues/100

Answer (score 1):

Tabulator does not have this functionality built in. It only provides headers at the top of the table